# User with different roles in different groups schema setup

Tags: php, mysql, database, schema, laravel

Im about to code a little game community in Laravel (4) and have some trouble figuring out how to set up the database tables. This is how it should work:

```
Users table:
John
Lisa
Stewie

Groups table:
Team red
Team blue
Team green

Roles table:
Superadmin
Admin
Moderator
Demigod

Permissions table: (describing what permissions each role has)
Superadmin (Total control of everything, will only be me and maybe a buddy with this role.)
Admin (create delete edit forums etc + everything a moderator does)
Moderator (delete forum posts, ban users)
Demigod (some other permissions)
```

A user, say Stewie can be in one or more teams. But he have different roles in each team.
Stewie - Team Red - Admin
Stewie - Team Blue - Moderator + Demigod

I'm wondering how do I set up this in a smart way?
First thing that comes to mind is a user_group pivot table. But how do i link that with roles specific to a group + user? Should I do some kind of three-way pivot table or can this be designed in some other way with a different table setup perhaps?

Comment: if you are looking for good packages than have a look for http://docs.cartalyst.com/sentry-2 its amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need a `membership` table like

```
Membership:
- membership_id
- user_id
- group_id
```

And a roles table:

```
Roles:
- membership_id
- role_id
```